# Using code to automatically click a mouse

Tags: automation, mouseclick-event

I'm working with a Bloomberg data sheet and I need to export this sheet into Excel.  The only way of doing so is through clicking the "export" button in the Bloomberg window.  Is there any way to use code to accomplish this click.  I would appreciate help with 1) indicating which coding language should be used 2) the physical code syntax that can accomplish my goal

I've tried using VBA, but there is no automatic control of the mouse.

Comment: Can you please specify which operating system are you using? 
Does the download happen via browser? Do you want something working out of box, or you're willing to code something for yourself?

Comment: I'm currently using microsoft windows.  Bloomberg is a computer software system that enables professionals in the financial sector to access market data.  Do you have any recommendations for a program that can manipulate my mouse to perform automatic functions like clicking the "export button" without someone manually moving the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives you may use to simulate mouse and keyboard automation on Windows platform.

1. [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com)
2. [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)

I would personally recommend using AutoHotKey. It has a very extensive documentation and a fairly active community.
Additionally, please try to use keyboard shortcuts (E.g Alt+F) instead of mouse movements. If you're using keyboard shortcuts, you'll be less prone to unwanted behaviour.

Extra: If you have a web application, you may use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org). It works neatly with Java or Python.

Comment: Should you chose to use AutoHotKey and require assistance, please feel free to create a new question and link in in the comments below. I'd be happy to help!